# Adobe Target Integration with SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, integration

I could have sworn the documentation for this under

> Home > Documentations > Email>integration > Adobe Target

less than a month ago, but it doesnt seem to be there anymore. Does anyone know if this has been taken out, moved or the integration is no longer available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct - it used to be there - it stills shows in their search index, but it has disappeared from the available articles

[image]

It normally appeared on this page:
https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/

Comment: This is very upsetting

Comment: It still shows on the adobe site: https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/content/resources/en/exchange/marketplace/apps/ExactTarget.html

Comment: That's actually the analytics connector and I think it's an rogue page

Comment: Okay , then i suppose support is the way to go?